# extract value from a column presto

Tags: sql, presto

i have two columns:

```
col1: Adam Smith
col2: [{"productId":"328608","invoiceId":"16150101","productType":"car"}]
```

i need to select this:

```
col1: Adam Smith
ProductId: 328608
```

any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: select products.productid from table1 result. query failed expression products is not type of row.

Answer (score 0):

More information is really needed to be specific but you're retrieving a value from a JSON object. You'll need to parse the column with a JSON function.

**MSSQL:**

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(COL2,'$[0].productId') FROM TABLE1
```

**PrestoDb**
[JSON Functions and Operators](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html)

```
SELECT json_extract_scalar(json, '$.store.book[0].author');
```

Comment: `json_extract_scalar(col2, '$[0].productId')` would be more appropriate, --- blindly assuming OP wants first element of `col2` and that `col2` is a JSON. (If OP wants all productIds then CROSS JOIN UNNEST would come handy)